# Switch tab in Firefox with swipe left/swipe right gestures

Tags: firefox, tabs, gesture

I have a MacBook and I'm using Firefox. Using the editor on the about:config page, I wish to modify the options of browser.gesture.swipe.left (or right) such that it will switch to the tab to the left (right) instead of going to previous/forward pages.

What should I write in the string value for that?

Thanks

Comment: Wish Firefox also had what Safari has in Window menu -> Show next tab. But since Ctrl + tab works there and also there's a preference for cycling in recent order, I think you should see what it modifies in the preferences under the hood to get some clues. (notify me by @ankii)

Comment: "I think you should see what it modifies in the preferences under the hood to get some clues. "

I'm not sure that I understand what do you mean by that...

Answer (score 2):

- Previous tab: `Browser:PrevTab`
- Next tab: `Browser:NextTab`

Reference of available commands:

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc

Comment: `browser.gesture.swipe.right;Browser:NextTab` and `browser.gesture.swipe.left;Browser:PrevTab` are relevant, But still couldn't get it to cycle tabs at swipe. Do you know about the ctrl tab switching? And also about the going back and forth in history ? I feel that clashes between the shortcuts need to be removed.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same here, I tried those settings but nothing happens.